# Toggling nested Table Columns - html, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm relatively new to jQuery but more seasoned using html and css.

I'm currently working on creating a new report that displays a nested table with quarterly results.[Sample Quarterly Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2Txh.png)
When a user clicks the img next to Q1 or Q2 table row - my expectation is for the Week (**wk**1 - **wk**n) columns to hide/show (toggle) as needed.
Additionally, when week columns are hidden, i would like the Quartely column(s) to collapse and dynamically show the **sum** of hidden weeks (wk1 - wkn).
Most of the code is borrowed from other posts but unfortunately, i was unable to find one that collapses and sums nested columns.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 
 var mImg = "http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:1PS9x2Ho4LHpaM:http://www.unesco.org/ulis/imag/minus.png";
 var pImg = "http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:4TZreCjs_a1eDM:http://www.venice.coe.int/images/plus.png";

     var sum1 = 0;
     $('tr').find('.combat1').each(function () {
         var combat1 = $(this).text();
         if (!isNaN(combat1) && combat1.length !== 0) {
             sum1 += parseFloat(combat1);
         }
     });
     var sum2 = 0;
     $('tr').find('.combat2').each(function () {
         var combat2 = $(this).text();
         if (!isNaN(combat2) && combat2.length !== 0) {
             sum2 += parseFloat(combat2);
         }
     });
     var sum3 = 0;
     $('tr').find('.combat3').each(function () {
         var combat3 = $(this).text();
         if (!isNaN(combat3) && combat3.length !== 0) {
             sum3 += parseFloat(combat3);
         }
     });

     $('.total-combat1').html(sum1);
     $('.total-combat2').html(sum2);
     $('.total-combat3').html(sum3);
     
     $('.header').click(function() {
                //$('td:nth-child(2)').hide();
                // if your table has header(th), use this
                $('td:nth-child(2),th:nth-child(2)').toggle();
            });
            
 });
```

```css
body {
    background: #80dfff;
    color: #d5d4d4;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: auto;
    padding: 30px;
}
table {
    background: white;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px #393939 solid;
    color: black;
    margin: 1em 1em 1em 0;
}
thead {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    color: black;
}
th, td {
    border: 1px #aaa solid;
    padding: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr><th colspan=8>2015</th></tr>
    <tr><th colspan=4 class="header">Q1 
    <img src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:1PS9x2Ho4LHpaM:http://www.unesco.org/ulis/imag/minus.png" />
        </th>
        <th colspan=3 class="header">Q2 
    <img src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:1PS9x2Ho4LHpaM:http://www.unesco.org/ulis/imag/minus.png" />
       </th>
       
        <th></th>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>WK1</th>
            <th>WK2</th>
            <th>WK3</th>
            <th>WK4</th>
            
            <th>WK1</th>
            <th>WK2</th>
            <th>WK3</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="combat1">8170</td>
            <td class="combat1">6504</td>
            <td class="combat1">6050</td>
            <td class="combat1">6050</td>
            
            <td class="combat1">7050</td>
            <td class="combat1">7050</td>
            <td class="combat1">7050</td>
            
            <td class="total-combat1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="combat2">8500</td>
            <td class="combat2">10200</td>
            <td class="combat2">7650</td>
            <td class="combat2">7650</td>
            
            <td class="combat2">8650</td>
            <td class="combat2">8650</td>
            <td class="combat2">8650</td>
            
            <td class="total-combat2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="combat3">9185</td>
            <td class="combat3">5515</td>
            <td class="combat3">6185</td>
            <td class="combat3">7185</td>
            
            <td class="combat3">9185</td>
            <td class="combat3">9185</td>
            <td class="combat3">9185</td>
            
            <td class="total-combat3"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to toggle the visibility of Q1 or Q2 you can change the header click event in order to obtain the effect produced in the following snippet.

The problem is to select all the cells of your interest and than toggle the visibility.

One way is to limit the cells selected using the jQuery [:lt](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) and [:gt](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) plus the [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function)

```js
$(function () {
  var mImg = "http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:1PS9x2Ho4LHpaM:http://www.unesco.org/ulis/imag/minus.png";
  var pImg = "http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:4TZreCjs_a1eDM:http://www.venice.coe.int/images/plus.png";

  var sum1 = 0;
  $('tr').find('.combat1').each(function () {
    var combat1 = $(this).text();
    if (!isNaN(combat1) && combat1.length !== 0) {
      sum1 += parseFloat(combat1);
    }
  });
  var sum2 = 0;
  $('tr').find('.combat2').each(function () {
    var combat2 = $(this).text();
    if (!isNaN(combat2) && combat2.length !== 0) {
      sum2 += parseFloat(combat2);
    }
  });
  var sum3 = 0;
  $('tr').find('.combat3').each(function () {
    var combat3 = $(this).text();
    if (!isNaN(combat3) && combat3.length !== 0) {
      sum3 += parseFloat(combat3);
    }
  });

  $('.total-combat1').html(sum1);
  $('.total-combat2').html(sum2);
  $('.total-combat3').html(sum3);


  // The new header click event

  $('.header').click(function(e) {
    var isVisible = false;
    var strSelector = '';
    var everyTotIndex = 4;
    if (this.innerText.trim() == 'Q1') {
      everyTotIndex = 4;
      strSelector = 'td:not([colspan="4"]):lt(4), th:not([colspan="4"]):lt(4)';
    } else {
      everyTotIndex = 3;
      strSelector = 'td:not([colspan="3"]):lt(7):gt(3), th:not([colspan="3"]):lt(7):gt(3)';
    }
    $(this).parents('table').find('tr:eq(2), tbody > tr').find(strSelector).css('display', function(index, value) {
      if (this.style.display == 'none') {
        isVisible = true;
        if ((index % everyTotIndex) == 0) {
          $(this).parent().find('td[colspan="' + everyTotIndex + '"], th[colspan="' + everyTotIndex + '"]').remove();
        }
        return '';
      }
      if ((index % everyTotIndex) == 0) {
        if (this.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'th') {
          $('<th colspan="' + everyTotIndex + '" class="total">Total</th>').insertBefore($(this));
        } else {
          $('<td colspan="' + everyTotIndex + '" class="combat1 total">0</td>').insertBefore($(this));
          var obj = $(this).parent().find('td[colspan="' + everyTotIndex + '"]');
          obj.text(+obj.text() + parseInt(this.textContent));
        }
      } else {
        if (this.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'td') {
          var obj = $(this).parent().find('td[colspan="' + everyTotIndex + '"]');
          obj.text(+obj.text() + parseInt(this.textContent));
        }
      }
      return 'none';
    });
    if (isVisible) {
      $(this).find('img').attr('src', "http://www.unesco.org/ulis/imag/minus.png");
    } else {
      $(this).find('img').attr('src', "http://www.unesco.org/ulis/imag/plus.png");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #80dfff;
  color: #d5d4d4;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 30px;
}
table {
  background: white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px #393939 solid;
  color: black;
  margin: 1em 1em 1em 0;
}
thead {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  color: black;
}
th, td {
  border: 1px #aaa solid;
  padding: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>


<table>
    <thead>
    <tr><th colspan=8>2015</th></tr>
    <tr><th colspan=4 class="header">Q1
        <img src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:1PS9x2Ho4LHpaM:http://www.unesco.org/ulis/imag/minus.png" />
    </th>
        <th colspan=3 class="header">Q2
            <img src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:1PS9x2Ho4LHpaM:http://www.unesco.org/ulis/imag/minus.png" />
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>WK1</th>
        <th>WK2</th>
        <th>WK3</th>
        <th>WK4</th>

        <th>WK1</th>
        <th>WK2</th>
        <th>WK3</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="combat1">8170</td>
        <td class="combat1">6504</td>
        <td class="combat1">6050</td>
        <td class="combat1">6050</td>

        <td class="combat1">7050</td>
        <td class="combat1">7050</td>
        <td class="combat1">7050</td>

        <td class="total-combat1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="combat2">8500</td>
        <td class="combat2">10200</td>
        <td class="combat2">7650</td>
        <td class="combat2">7650</td>

        <td class="combat2">8650</td>
        <td class="combat2">8650</td>
        <td class="combat2">8650</td>

        <td class="total-combat2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="combat3">9185</td>
        <td class="combat3">5515</td>
        <td class="combat3">6185</td>
        <td class="combat3">7185</td>

        <td class="combat3">9185</td>
        <td class="combat3">9185</td>
        <td class="combat3">9185</td>

        <td class="total-combat3"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi gaemaf - Thanks for the quick turnaround. Much appreciated.
I have modified my initial question above to clarify what i was looking to archive. In addition to a total column at the end, i would also like to sum and display quarter totals (wk1 - wkn) once the quarter column (e.g. Q1) is collapsed. Additionally, i was looking to have the quarterly column collapse when the hide event is triggered (to save some real estate). Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Great!! That's what I was looking for. Thanks a bunch gaemaf

Comment: One quick add, when i click on Q1 it works well. However, when i click on Q2 things go funky! Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to figure out what you was trying to do... Correct if me I wrong: you're trying to toggle the set of columns under, for e.g. Q1, when you click on the header column? If so, here the code. I modified your code, I added to nested tables under the main table to organize/ divide the two sets of information so I can select easily with jQuery which one I'm going to toggle.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var mImg = "http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:1PS9x2Ho4LHpaM:http://www.unesco.org/ulis/imag/minus.png";
  var pImg = "http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:4TZreCjs_a1eDM:http://www.venice.coe.int/images/plus.png";

  var sum1 = 0;
  $('tr').find('.combat1').each(function() {
    var combat1 = $(this).text();
    if (!isNaN(combat1) && combat1.length !== 0) {
      sum1 += parseFloat(combat1);
    }
  });
  var sum2 = 0;
  $('tr').find('.combat2').each(function() {
    var combat2 = $(this).text();
    if (!isNaN(combat2) && combat2.length !== 0) {
      sum2 += parseFloat(combat2);
    }
  });
  var sum3 = 0;
  $('tr').find('.combat3').each(function() {
    var combat3 = $(this).text();
    if (!isNaN(combat3) && combat3.length !== 0) {
      sum3 += parseFloat(combat3);
    }
  });


  $('.header-1').click(function() {
    $("#table1").toggle();
  });

  $('.header-2').click(function() {
    $("#table2").toggle();
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  color: #d5d4d4;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 30px;
}
table {
  background: white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px #393939 solid;
  color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
thead {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  color: black;
}
th,
td,
tr {
  border: 1px #aaa solid;
  padding: 0;
}
td.combat {
  padding: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan=2>2015</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="header-1">Q1
        <img src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:1PS9x2Ho4LHpaM:http://www.unesco.org/ulis/imag/minus.png" />
      </th>
      <th class="header-2">Q2
        <img src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:1PS9x2Ho4LHpaM:http://www.unesco.org/ulis/imag/minus.png" />
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table id="table1">
          <tr>
            <th>WK1</th>
            <th>WK2</th>
            <th>WK3</th>
            <th>WK4</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="combat combat1">8170</td>
            <td class="combat combat1">6504</td>
            <td class="combat combat1">6050</td>
            <td class="combat combat1">6050</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td class="combat combat1">8170</td>
            <td class="combat combat1">6504</td>
            <td class="combat combat1">6050</td>
            <td class="combat combat1">6050</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table id="table2">
          <tr>
            <th>WK1</th>
            <th>WK2</th>
            <th>WK3</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="combat combat2">7050</td>
            <td class="combat combat2">7050</td>
            <td class="combat combat2">7050</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="combat combat2">7050</td>
            <td class="combat combat2">7050</td>
            <td class="combat combat2">7050</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick Turnaround Aymen Ben Tanfous.

Comment: I have modified my initial question above to clarify what i was looking to archive. In addition to a total column at the end, i would also like to sum and display quarter totals (wk1 - wkn) once the quarter column (e.g. Q1) is collapsed. Thanks again.